# InDesign XML import -- am I missing something?

Tags: adobe-indesign, xml

I'm trying to create a flyer, using InDesign CS6, for which the content is imported from XML, but I'm struggling...

This is my InDesign template:
[image: InDesign template]

I've tagged the individual text elements I need to replace and the text frame is tagged *Specifications*. My XML looks like this:

[image: XML data]

What I would expect is that the FlagState, TradingArea, etc. tags are replaced by the XML content on import. However, what I end up with is all my descriptions and titles gone, and additional tabs inserted in their place:

[image: Import results]

I've tried al sorts of import options, all to no avail :( For this example this are the options used:

[image: Import options]

Questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong -- am I missing something?
2. Is what I am trying to do possible at all using InDesign?

All input is appreciated!

Comment: are your tags mapping to paragraph styles?

Comment: No, I have made no mappings to any styles. Should I?

Comment: No, just curious.  Looking at your example, it may be your tabs.  Maybe try reformatting the text with consistent tabs?  Somehow you look to be getting an extra tab.  Maybe two are overlapping eachother?

Comment: It *does* look like the tabs outside the xml delimiters are being inserted. Maybe also try: duplicate the xml file and remove all tabs. Also the heads are missing.

Comment: yes adobe reads the tabs by default. I think therewas a way to disable it.